# Repeat normality check after modifying group cut-off?

Tags: normality-assumption, robust, group-differences

I have a set of data which consists of one independent variable (2 groups) and one dependent variable. I successfully checked for normality (each group separately) and conducted a t-test.

Now I want to check for robustness by changing the cut-off between groups.

Do I have to also do another normality check first with the different group cut-off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you are going to modify the cut-off to get different groups and then repeat the t-test to see if your results are similar.  If that is the case, then you will have to check normality again each time you do the t-test with different defined groups.  Normality is an assumption of the t-test, so you should check the assumption before you run each t-test if you want the outcome of the test to be meaningful.

Comment: Yes, you do understand me correctly, the idea is to check how important the way is how the groups are divided and if the result is the same with a slightly different approach. Thanks for your answer